# Formatting tables with ng-repeat to have cells beside each other with different data

Tags: angularjs

Hello each and everyone,

I have an app, where I would have to be able to use ng-repeat to display data like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZPHyx/

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="cell">Tom Hanks</td>
            <td>Tom Cruice</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bruce Willis</td>
            <td>Leonardo DiCaprio</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ellen Page</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>        
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So, I have a list of things I would like to be able to present in table or similar, so that two items are listed beside each other. Each of the items are in identical, except of course the data in them is not...

Is it possible and how to do it? I tried using custom filter, but it prints the html-tags as well not rendering the string / data to html.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

So in plain Javascript it would be something like:

```
var str "";

for (var i = 0; ii < people.length; i = i + 2) {
    var person1 = people[ii];
    var person2 = people[ii + 1];

    str+= "<tr><td>" + person1.name + "</td><td>" + person2.name + "</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: Are the items coming out of a single list, and you're wanting to arrange them with items 1 and 2 on the first row, 3 and 4 on the second, etc? Or are the left and right columns coming out of different lists? The answer to 'is it possible' is yes, but 'how to do it' will depend on the structure of your data.

Comment: I fetch a list of people from MongoDB and then would like to present them as I specified above. So basically I would have to be able to print every other person's data to right and every other to left. So 1 st person to left, 2nd person to right, 3rd person to left etc.

Comment: This is more of an aside, but if you're trying to achieve a specific layout, than this is not how HTML tables should be used. They should be used for structured display of information. If you just want to put the actors next to each other, better use divs and css.

Comment: My CSS-knowledge is not so good, so an example would help a lot! :D

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jayx/Qbz9S/1/) is a fiddle that shows how you can achieve two columns strictly using HTML and CSS with an unordered list.  From here it should be simple to use an ng-repeat to generate the list and display.

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in itemList">
    <li>{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

I believe that the link is using CSS3 to set some of the margins, but that could be replaced with $index and ng-class.